# Powershell script to add computer in AD

Tags: powershell

I am getting the below error while trying to add a computer object in AD by using Powershell.

```
New-ADComputer -Name <Computer Name> -Path 'OU=Devices,DC=enterprise,DC=com' -Enabled $True

Error: New-ADComputer : A required attribute is missing
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing `-SamAccountName`

Answer (score 0):

See example 1 at [New-ADComputer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adcomputer?view=win10-ps). I guess the parameter `-SamAccountName` is missing.

```
New-ADComputer -Name "USER02-SRV2" -SamAccountName "USER02-SRV2" -Path "OU=ApplicationServers,OU=ComputerAccounts,OU=Managed,DC=USER02,DC=COM"
```

Comment: It is not working still

New-ADComputer -Name 'ComputerName' -SamAccountName 'ComputerName' -Path OU=Devices,DC=enterprise,DC=com' -Enabled $True

New-ADComputer : A required attribute is missing
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADComputer -Name 'ComputerName' -SamAccountName 'ComputerName' -Path 'OU= ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=USER02-SRV2,OU=...C=enterprise,DC=com:String) [New-ADComputer], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8316,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADComputer

Comment: Enter the command `New-ADComputer` directly into powershell.exe (without parameters). Powershell will ask for all needed parameters and you will see what is missing and if the command is working with the values you provide.

Comment: The command `New-ADComputer -Name 'tst-srv' -SAMAccountName 'tst-srv' -Path 'OU=Test,DC=local,DC=com' -Enabled $True` works for me without an.

Comment: I am getting the below error

New-ADComputer : A required attribute is missing
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADComputer -Name 'tst-srv' -SamAccountName 'tst-srv' -Path 'OU= ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=tst-srv,OU=...C=testdc,DC=com:String) [New-ADComputer], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8316,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADComputer